# ¿Cómo unir dos strings a un tercer string y que este quede ordenado?

Tags: c, string

estoy aprendiendo a programar desde cero y en C. Seguramente la solución sea muy sencilla pero realmente no sé ni por donde empezar. Los string serían: `char a[] = {'a', 'c', 'e', 'g'};`  `char b[] = {'b', 'd', 'f', 'h'};` `char c[9];` Calculo que va 9 en la dimensión porque va a incluir los 8 caracteres y "\0", la idea es que `char c[9];` termine siendo: `char c[9] = "abcdefg";`

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: lo que buscas es unir dos arrays y ordenarlos, ya que de por sí los arrays no son ordenados.

Comment: Añade uno de un lado y uno del otro. Puedes hacerlo con un `for` y separandolos con un modulo.

Comment: Debes concatenar las cadenas usando la función [strcat](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcat/), luego ordena el array `c` con la función [qsort](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/qsort/). Por cierto, si vas a inicializar el array de esa forma, no olvides de agregarle el caracter nulo al final, porque el compilador no lo hará por ti y esto ocasiona un [comportamiento indefinido](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comportamiento_indefinido) en el programa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La forma que te voy a presentar solo sirve si las letras están intercaladas y con arrays del mismo tamaño, es decir si una letra mayor se encuentra en el otro array, no he implementado ningún algoritmo de ordenamiento. Dado que las letras faltantes se encuentran en el otro array podemos hacer una doble inserción de elementos, es decir, en la posición `c[i]` insertamos `a[i]` y en `c[i+1]` insertamos `b[i]`.

```c
int main()
{
    int n=0; //variable para saber posicion a insertar elemento adicional
    char c[9];
    char a[] = {'a', 'c', 'e', 'g'};
    char b[] = {'b', 'd', 'f', 'h'};
    
    //obtenemos los tamaños
    int size_a = sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);
    int size_c = sizeof(c)/sizeof(c[0]);
    
    //recorremos segun el tamaño del arrar a
    for (int i=0; i < size_a; i++) {
        c[n] = a[i]; //insertamos en la posicion n
        c[n+1] = b[i]; //insertamos una posicion despues
        n = n+2;
    }
    
    //recorremos para imprimir
    for ( int i=0; i<size_c; i++){
        printf("%c", c[i]);
    }
}
```

**salida**

```
abcdefgh
```